# Error in mounted hook (Promise/async) when fetching data from the server

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js

I'm new to Vue, I have a WebPage component(movie song list) that receives a movie_id from the page route parameters (through this.$store.state.route.params.movieId), then fetches the actual user song data from the database on the server using a command: this.movie = (await MoviesService.show(movieId)).data, the show function is to find the params in db by id and send the content back to front end.

My question is that whenever I click on the view button, the website will link to the certain id page with a basic frame, but it can't get the content in the movie song list web page. [The error demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGglb.gif) [The snapshot in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEtHU.png)

The error shows in the console is:

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook (Promise/async): "Error: Request
>   failed with status code 500" found in --->  at
>   src/components/ViewMovie.vue  at src/App.vue

ViewMovie.vue:

```
<template>
<panel title= "Movies theme song list">
      <div class="movie-title">
          {{movie.title}}
      </div>
      <div class="movie-artist">
          {{movie.artist}}
      </div>
      <div class="movie-album">
          {{movie.album}}
      </div>
      </panel>
</template>

<script>
import MoviesService from '@/services/MoviesService'
import Panel from '@/components/Panel'
export default {
  async mounted () {
    const movieId = this.$store.state.route.params.movieId
    this.movie = (await MoviesService.show(movieId)).data
  },
  data () {
    return {
      movie: {}
    }
  },
  components: {
    Panel
  }
}
</script>
```

MoviesController.js:

```
const {Movie} = require('../models')

module.exports = {
  async show (req, res) {
    try {
      const movie = await Movie.findById(req.params.movieId)
      res.send(movie)
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).send({
        error: 'An error has occured trying to fetch the movie'
      })
    }
  },
  async post (req, res) {
    try {
      const movie = await Movie.create(req.body)
      res.send(movie)
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).send({
        error: 'An error has occured trying to create the movie'
      })
    }
  }
}
```

MoviesService.js:

```
import Api from '@/services/Api'

export default {
  index () {
    return Api().get('movies')
  },
  show (movieId) {
    return Api().get(`movies/${movieId}`)
  },
  post (movie) {
    return Api().post('movies', movie)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see your actual movie object in the database so i am going to go partially on assumptions.

findById() is how you are attempting to find the movie. YOUR ID is 1. FindById() expects the data in the _id field that is auto-generated. The _id is something more along the lines of `5d8c369e69ccb034cc31b816`

if you change:

```
await Movie.findById(req.params.movieId)
```

to

```
await Movie.findOne({ id: { $eq: req.params.movieId })
```

change id here to ID if your database object has those letters capitalized.

What do you get? Any change?

might be worth showing a raw object with the whole movie database entry to see what all is in there and help further if i'm on the wrong path...

Comment: changed find() to findOne() to avoid returning array and causing separate possible tweaks needed

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! I suppose that findById() will trigger the findOne() middleware,  so is it because I'm passing in an object with an id property rather than a string or ObjectId instance?

Comment: findById(id) is just a slightly cleaner syntax for findOne({_id:id}).

Comment: Sorry to bother, I have another problem after getting the content from the song list page. The findOne() works well in fetching the content by id in the first id page, but the following id pages(i.e. id:2) all gets the same content in the first id page,  I'm wondering if the webpage only receives the first movie_id data? [error: https://imgur.com/a/Yi6kn9y]

Comment: My first answer still hasn't even been marked as what you needed. Your image link doesn't seem to work so i cant see the error you are receiving now.

Comment: Sorry, just marked. Can you try these links? [1]: https://imgur.com/M0HXAQz [2]: https://reurl.cc/pdA62Q [3]: https://imgur.com/ZsPKeDi [4]: https://reurl.cc/oLA735 ? Thanks

Comment: imgur files show broken images and reurl just gives an error. How about copy and paste of the actual text of the error?

Comment: Actually, it's not an error, it's just that the other route will all link to the same page, but thanks again for your help.